# Hibernate multiple foreign key

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I am new to hibernate.

My problem is to resolve multiple Foreign Keys to their Value. I am able to do it with SQL but the Hibernate Annotations makes me crazy.

I got these 2 Tables for example:

### Table MoveSets

- MoveSet_ID
- Punch_1
- Punch_2
- Graple_1
- Graple_2
- Graple_3
- Graple_4

### Table Moves

- Move_ID
- Name
- Damage
- MoveType_ID
- Counterchance

The Punches and Graples are all foreign keys referencing to Move_ID.

My target is to do a `session.createQuery("from MoveSets").list();` and to get a Moveset with the Names of the Moves instead of the IDs.

Is this possible in Hibernate?

```
package hibernate;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Moves")
public class Moves implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -1522367877613954187L;
private int id;
private String name;
private int damage;
private int movetype_id;
private int counterchance;

public Moves() {

}

public Moves(int id, String name, int damage, int movetype_id,
        int counterchance) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.damage = damage;
    this.movetype_id = movetype_id;
    this.counterchance = counterchance;
}

@Id
@Column(name = "Move_ID")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
@GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name = "Name")
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Column(name = "Damage")
public int getDamage() {
    return damage;
}

public void setDamage(int damage) {
    this.damage = damage;
}

@Column(name = "MoveType_ID")
public int getMovetype_id() {
    return movetype_id;
}

public void setMovetype_id(int movetype_id) {
    this.movetype_id = movetype_id;
}

@Column(name = "Counterchance")
public int getCounterchance() {
    return counterchance;
}

public void setCounterchance(int counterchance) {
    this.counterchance = counterchance;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Moves - Name: " + name;
}
}
```

And

```
package hibernate;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

@Entity
@Table(name = "MoveSets")
public class MoveSets implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -6488498413048804953L;

private int id;
private int punch_1;
private int punch_2;
private int graple_1;
private int graple_2;
private int graple_3;
private int graple_4;

public MoveSets() {

}

public MoveSets(int id, int punch_1, int punch_2, int graple_1,
        int graple_2, int graple_3, int graple_4) {
    this.id = id;
    this.punch_1 = punch_1;
    this.punch_2 = punch_2;
    this.graple_1 = graple_1;
    this.graple_2 = graple_2;
    this.graple_3 = graple_3;
    this.graple_4 = graple_4;
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "Moves_ID")
public Moves moves;

@Id
@Column(name = "MoveSet_ID")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
@GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name = "Punch_1")
public int getPunch_1() {
    return punch_1;
}

public void setPunch_1(int punch_1) {
    this.punch_1 = punch_1;
}

@Column(name = "Punch_2")
public int getPunch_2() {
    return punch_2;
}

public void setPunch_2(int punch_2) {
    this.punch_2 = punch_2;
}

@Column(name = "Graple_1")
public int getGraple_1() {
    return graple_1;
}

public void setGraple_1(int graple_1) {
    this.graple_1 = graple_1;
}

@Column(name = "Graple_2")
public int getGraple_2() {
    return graple_2;
}

public void setGraple_2(int graple_2) {
    this.graple_2 = graple_2;
}

@Column(name = "Graple_3")
public int getGraple_3() {
    return graple_3;
}

public void setGraple_3(int graple_3) {
    this.graple_3 = graple_3;
}

@Column(name = "Graple_4")
public int getGraple_4() {
    return graple_4;
}

public void setGraple_4(int graple_4) {
    this.graple_4 = graple_4;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "MoveSet - ID: " + id + " Punch 1: " + punch_1;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: added code to original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible, in fact the whole point of ORM and Hibernate is to get objects (your values) insteed of plain IDs. Your mapping is wrong. You should map your relations (I assume that punches and grapples are moves) via annotations like `@OneToOne`,`@OneToMany` and so one along with `@JoinColumn`, so your fields insteed of this

```
@Column(name = "Graple_1")
public int getGraple_1() {
    return graple_1;
}
```

should be like

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="Graple1")
public Move getGraple_1() {
    return graple_1;
}
```

This way you will get relevant `Move` objects and get any data you want from them, along with the requested `name`

Comment: this solved my problems. Thank you and sorry for this late answer.